# C# System.PlatformID.Unix vs. Linux

Tags: vb.net, linux, unix, mono

Question:

I need to make some system calls in my C# applications.
Unfortunately, this behaves differently on Linux than on UNIX.

Now I used to switch the Operating system at runtime like this

```
If Environment.OSVersion.Platform = System.PlatformID.Unix Then
    ' Linux/Unix '
ElseIf Environment.OSVersion.Platform = System.PlatformID.MacOSX Then
    ' Apple '
Else
    ' Windows '
End If
```

The problem now is I need to differentiate between UNIX and Linux, because they are different.

Is there a way I can figure out whether the OS is Linux or Unix?
Preferably not by invoking uname -a

I wouldn't like to abandon Unix and make it Linux only, just because Microsoft did not add a PlatformID.Linux...

Comment: It's a bit childish to use spellings such as "CrApple" and "Windoze".

Comment: I use Windoze. I've never heard CrApple before that's great! I don't see where it is tho in the OP.

Comment: @siride: Indeed, and I shouldn't have capizalized the A ;-))

Comment: You may be slightly confused.  Linux _is_ a Unix, though not a UNIX; OS X is both a Unix and a UNIX.  Perhaps you should be checking for functionality, instead.

Comment: Linux is the abbrevation for Linux Is NOT UniX. Linux is a superset of Unix. Not a subset and not equal. I am aware that  Unix is a standard, while UNIX is a kernel.

Comment: 1 downvote and 1 close vote. Somebody here has no sense of humor. Besides, I am annoyed, not childish. But the symptoms are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use "uname -a" to distinguish Linux from Unix, as well as OSX.  For historical reasons, Mono reports OSX as Unix, not MacOSX.

Some code that uses uname is available here:
http://github.com/jpobst/Pinta/blob/master/Pinta/Platform.cs

Comment: OS X a Unix. That's a bad joke - well unfortunately it's not a joke. It's missing the ENTIRE proc subsystem, and it also has a completely changed ptrace interface. Well, so much to 'preferably not by invoking uname -a'. +1 for the codesample, though.

Comment: @pra: True, it's not in the standard, but FreeBSD has it.

Comment: All of these operating systems have deviated so far from Unix as it was intended to be implemented that we can either call them all Unix-like and group them, or give up on Unix altogether.